# Loop using jquery each and not td : nth child(3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Im looking to change this code because `nth-child(3)` is not working on IE8. How can I change this and other part of my code to  `jquery.each` in jquery?

```
var allValues = $('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();
```

[see FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kony5vuo/)

Comment: jQuery's [`:nth-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) will work on IE8. Just use a jQuery version that [actually supports IE8](http://jquery.com/browser-support/). Hint: It's not 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to use `.each()`; you can use filter to perform the work of `nth-child` like so:

```
var allValues = $('#myTable td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('tr').children('td').index( this ) === 2;
})
.find('input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();
```

Please bear in mind that [**jQuery 2.x supports IE > 8.**](http://code.jquery.com/)

```
 var inputs = $('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == value; });
```

Would be:

```
var inputs = $('#myTable td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('tr').children('td').index( this ) === 2;
})
.find('input').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == value; });
```

Comment: Can you help on my 2nd code whic also have `nth-child`?

Comment: It should be the same principle; is it in the demo?

Comment: Yes, its on my demo, this line of code `  var inputs = $('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == value; });`